# How to remap the meta key on Linux?

Tags: keyboard-layout

How can I make an alternative keyboard key (e.g. the Windows key) act as the meta key in emacs?

I am looking for a solution internal to emacs, so using xmodmap is out of the question.

Comment: You can remap keys per application (by having the window manager switch mappings on a window focus switch), but I don't know of a convenient way to do that. [Xxkb](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xxkb/) does layout switching but I don't know how to configure it to move modifiers around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following elisp may help you out. Just add it to your config.

```
(setq x-meta-keysym 'super)
```

Comment: Thanks! The line (setq x-super keysym 'meta) did the trick, but is not taking effect when running emacs in the terminal.

Comment: @explaw Doing this in a terminal is completely different and may or may not be possible depending on which terminal emulator you use. You should ask a new question about this (since you mentioned xmodmap as an alternative here, your question was implicitly about X11).

Comment: This was helpful; I did `(setq x-super-keysym 'meta)` to make GUI emacs work for as I wanted in Ubuntu